# Javascript how to add and remove JSON element which is on 2 level deep

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular

I googled and monkey around a lot on how to remove elements from my JSON object.

Here is my simplified JSON to illustrate my requirement.

bundle:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2017-10-06T04:42:22.411Z"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": "0",
    "entry": [
        {
            "_id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d6a831e4b45d50c5ffd4fa",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a831e4b45d50c5ffd4fa"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

How to remove ALL entry._id and entry.__v?
I tried these, but not working.

```
delete bundle.meta;   <-- meta is on level 1, it works.
delete bundle.entry._id; <-- not working. The _id under entry
delete bundle.__v; <-- not working. The __v is also under entry
```

How can I add a new element under each entry such as "fullname" as below

My desired result - remove '_id' and '__v', then add 'fullname' to the entry[]:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2017-10-06T04:42:22.411Z"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": "0",
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullname": "Apple",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d",
            }
        },
        {
            "fullname": "Orange",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7"
            },
        }, ......
```

I have tried many ways and googled a lot. Thanks for the help!

---

**Thanks Vivek for the answer. It works.**

```
for (var i = 0; i < bundle.entry.length; i++) {
    delete bundle.entry[i]._id;
    delete bundle.entry[i].__v;
    bundle.entry[i].fullname = "Test";
}
```

Comment: _"My desired result - remove '_id' and '__v', then add 'fullname' to the entry[]"_ How is `"fullname"` property value determined?

Comment: You can't remove elements from the [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ...

Comment: Hi guest271314, let's say the entry[i].fullname = last 4 digit of entry[i].resource.id; Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below. Tested it can help you.

```
  var object1 = {
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2017-10-06T04:42:22.411Z"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": "0",
    "entry": [
        {
            "_id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d",
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d6a831e4b45d50c5ffd4fa",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a831e4b45d50c5ffd4fa"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
  };

  var array1=['Apple','Orange','Gava']

  function a(){
        for(var i=0;i<object1.entry.length;i++){
            delete object1.entry[i]._id;
            delete object1.entry[i].__v;
            object1.entry[i].fullname = array1[i];
        }
        console.log(object);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

bundle.entry is an Array. :) 
**delete _id of first element:**
`delete bundle.entry[0]._id`
**delete _id and __v of all element:**
`bundle.entry = bundle.entry.map(function(entry){
    var newEntry = {
       resource: entry.resource,
       fullname: "fullname here"
    };
    return newEntry;
});`

Comment: This will add the same `fullname` in every entry. Which is not desired

Answer (score 1):

```
const fullNameList = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Guava']
delete bundle.meta
bundle.entry = bundle.entry.map((item, index) => {
    const {__v, _id, ...restObj } = item;
    restObj.fullname = fullNameList[index]
    return restObj;
})
```

mind that the `fullNameList`'s length and the `bundle.entry`'s length must be the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map function and remove the keys from the object, and add keys in the same function, as shown below:

```js
var data = {
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2017-10-06T04:42:22.411Z"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": "0",
    "entry": [
        {
            "_id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d5739e668e9e3fd29aeb0d"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a3fae4b45d50c5ffd4f7"
            },
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d6a831e4b45d50c5ffd4fa",
            "resource": {
                "id": "59d6a831e4b45d50c5ffd4fa"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
var names = ['A','B','C'];
var counter = 0;
data.entry = data.entry.map(function(obj){
    delete obj['_id']
    delete obj['__v']
    obj.fullname = names[counter]
    counter++ ;
    return obj
});

console.log(data);
```